# K&R book exercise 4-2

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm studying K&R book. I'm currently at chapter 4. I was reading the atof() function on page 71. Function atof(s) converts string to its double precision floating point equivalent.

The code of atof() is as following:
//atof: convert string s to double

```
double atof2(char s[])
{
   double val, power;
   int i, sign;

   for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); ++i) //skip white space
       ;
   sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1: 1;
   if (s[i] == '-' || s[i] == '-')
       ++i;

   for (val = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
       val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');

   if (s[i] == '.')
       ++i;
   for (power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++) {
       val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');
       power *= 10.0;
   }

   return sign * val / power;
```

}

My question is about variable: power. Why do we need it for?

I do understand the use of variable: "val" but i'm not sure about variable: "power". Why do we divide val by power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable `power` is for division of number by power , to get result as float point .

Let your string be `-12.83` , then  first `for` loop will check for space and increment `i` as no space so ,`i=0` .

`sign` will be `-1` as `s[i]=s[0]='-'` .

In next two loops string's values are converted to integers and stored in `val` ( *excluding* `.` - figure out yourself) .

Now after both loop `val` will be `1283` .  But last loop will iterate for `2` times and `power` will be changed to `100.00` (`10*1.0` in first iteration and `10*10.0` in second iteration) .

Now to get value as float point `val` is divided by `power`  and multiplied by `sign` .

So , what it will return is `-1*1283/100` , thus `-12.83` is your float point number .

Comment: Ok. But why they used two loops: 1) for (val = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
       val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0'); and 2) for (power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++) {
       val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');
       power *= 10.0;
   } Can't we simply merge both for loops in one loop as follows: for (val = 0.0, power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++) {
       val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');
       power *= 10.0;
   } I hope i made my question clear?

Comment: @HusseinBarada First one to convert string to numbers until `'.'` is encountered . It ends as any non-digit is encountered. Second loop is to covert characters after `'.'` to numbers .

Comment: @HusseinBarada `-12.83`  first loop will convert  first two characters (_after_  `'-'` in string) to integers and store in `val` , and second loop will do it for characters after `'.'`

Comment: @HusseinBarada  This `if (s[i] == '.')++i;` is to get index of `'.'` and then increment `i`  and use it in second loop .  This `if` is to take action as `'.'` is encountered .

Comment: ok got it. The whole function makes more sense to me. Thanks for your help @ameyCU